Chance of success/Number of Points Scored in an inverted BitD-esque dice pool
I'm working on a GM-less game that encourages you to make things difficult for your own characters, to that end I've developed an "inverted" BitD-style dice pool where more dice=more chance of failure, at the same time more dice also means more chance of reward.
You roll xd6, where x is the likelihood of something bad happening on a scale of 1 through 5. At the same time you define the Danger Level of the roll on a scale of 1-5 as well.

If any dice lands on 6 you get a bad result and suffer the danger
If no dice land on 6 but any land on 1 you get a complicated result and suffer the danger but also gain something narratively
If no dice land on 6 or 1 you get a good result and gain something narratively without suffering a consequence.
On a complicated or good result you may also -possibly- reduce the Difficulty of the scene, this is an Ironsworn-style probabilistic success clock used to resolve scenes during the climactic moment. On a complicated or good result you reduce the difficulty of the scene by 1 for every dice that lands on a number less than or equal to the Danger Level (not the difficulty, but also on a scale of 1-5)

You might notice this means you can get a good result while also not reducing the difficulty of the climax roll (which uses the same system where more dice=more chance of badness). You might also notice that a Complicated result always results in at least 1 point earned, this is intentional to get players to crank up the difficulty and not be averse to the possibility of failure.
I've been capable of modeling rules 1-3 with a simple anydice script (output x@xd6{0,1,1,1,1,-1} , where -1 equals a bad result, 0 equals a complicated result, and 1 equals a good result mapped to a six sided die).
I need help with rule 4! I need all of the following outcomes/outputs: 1 through 5d6 with difficulty 1 through 5 (25 permutations total) with the chance of the following outputs:

Bad Outcome
Complicated outcome w/ 1-x points (where x=the total number of dice, the higher the danger level the more likely each dice will score a point, complicated is always at least 1 point)
Good outcome w/ zero points
Good outcome w/ 1-x points (where x is the total number of dice dictated by the difficulty).

So, as an example, difficulty 5 danger 5 rolls 5 dice, with the following potential results:

Bad Outcome (very high)
Complicated Outcome 1 point
Complicated Outcome 2 points
Complicated Outcome 3 points
Complicated Outcome 4 points
Complicated Outcome 5 points
Good Outcome 0 points
Good Outcome 1 points
Good Outcome 2 points
Good Outcome 3 points
Good Outcome 4 points
Good Outcome 5 points (very low)


So if the danger level is 1, you can't reduce the difficulty of the scene without a complicated result, and it gets easier to reduce the difficulty of the scene as the danger level rises?

Exactly correct, only danger 2 or higher can get a Good Outcome while also scoring points and reducing the Scene Difficulty.

Since AnyDice only has integer outcomes, the way to jointly output multiple types of results is to put them in different digits. With only up to five dice, we can put the points in a single digit. It's easiest to use a function in this case, taking the roll of the pool using a parameter of type sequence:
function: ibitd S:s vs D:n {
 if S = 6 {
  result: -10
 }
 result: (S <= D) + 10 * ((S = 1) = 0)
}

output [ibitd 5d6 vs 3]

AnyDice link.

The result has the type of outcome in the tens digit (-10 = bad, 10 = good, complicated otherwise), and the number of points in the ones digit (unless bad).
When you apply a comparator with a number on one side and a sequence on the other, it compares that number with each element of the sequence and counts how many fit the comparison. So S = 6 counts the number of 6s and S <= D counts how many dice rolled lower or equal to the danger.


https://anydice.com/program/3a22a This is the code I've been using to represent rules 1-3.

Ah, sorry, I missed that you took the last element of the pool. That part is correct then.
